# How to separate user's name and the text inside a chat box?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

As it is now in my chat the username, time and message are all appearing in the same chatbox when the message is sent. How do I achieve this. This is the code:

```
const MessageList = ({ messages, userId }) => {
  const el = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    el.current.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className='message-list'>
        {Object.keys(messages)
          .map((messageKey) => ({ ...messages[messageKey], id: messageKey }))
          .map((message) => (
            <div key={message.id}>
              {userId === message.author ? (
                <li className='listed-items' style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }}>
                  <div className='message-chat'>
                    <p className='message-text'>
                      <p className='message-user'>
                        {message.userFirstname + ' ' + message.userLastname}
                        <span style={{ display: 'list-item' }}>
                          {message.role == 'Client'
                            ? 'Kunde'
                            : message.role == 'Craftsman'
                            ? 'Håndværker'
                            : 'Admin'}
                        </span>
                      </p>
                      <p className='message-time'>
                        {moment(message.created).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm')}
                      </p>
                    </p>
                    <p className='message-content'>{message.text}</p>
                  </div>
                </li>
              ) : (
                <li
                  className='listed-otheritems'
                  style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }}
                >
                  <div className='message-otherchat'>
                    <p className='message-othertext'>
                      <p className='message-otheruser'>
                        {message.userFirstname + ' ' + message.userLastname}
                        <span style={{ display: 'list-item' }}>
                          {message.role == 'Client'
                            ? 'Kunde'
                            : message.role == 'Craftsman'
                            ? 'Håndværker'
                            : 'Admin'}
                        </span>
                      </p>
                      <p className='message-othertime'>
                        {moment(message.created).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm')}
                      </p>
                    </p>
                    {message.text === '' ? (
                      <p className='message-othercontent'>
                        <img height='300' width='200' src={message.imageId} />
                      </p>
                    ) : (
                      <p className='message-othercontent'>{message.text}</p>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </li>
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
      </ul>
      <div id={'el'} ref={el}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MessageList;
```

And here's a screenshot of how it looks:
[image]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]

All ideas are most welcome. I've tried so many css hacks but nothing seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

---

as i see in image you can do this but ihop i undrestand what you want.

```
  const MessageList = ({ messages, userId }) => {
  const el = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    el.current.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' });
  });

return (
  <div>
    <ul className='message-list'>
      {Object.keys(messages)
        .map((messageKey) => ({ ...messages[messageKey], id: messageKey }))
        .map((message) => (
         <div key={message.id}>
            {userId === message.author ? (
              <li className='listed-items' style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }}>
                <div className='message-chat'>
                  <p className='message-text'>
                    <p className='message-user'>
                      {message.userFirstname + ' ' + message.userLastname}
                      <span style={{ display: 'list-item' }}>
                        {message.role == 'Client'
                          ? 'Kunde'
                          : message.role == 'Craftsman'
                          ? 'Håndværker'
                          : 'Admin'}
                      </span>
                    </p>
                    <p className='message-time'>
                      {moment(message.created).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm')}
                    </p>
                  </p>
                  <p className='message-content'>{message.text}</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            ) : (
              <li
                className='listed-otheritems'
                style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }}
                <div className='message-otherchat'>
                  <p className='message-othertext'>
                    <p className='message-otheruser'>
                      {message.userFirstname + ' ' + message.userLastname}
                      {message.text === '' ? (
                      <img height='300' width='200' src={message.imageId} />
                  ) : (
                  {message.text}
                  )}
                  }
                </div>
              </li>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
    </ul>
    <div id={'el'} ref={el}></div>
  </div>
  );
  };
 export default MessageList;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what changes did you make? I can't see them, I see exactly the same code. As I stated above I just want to separate the username and datetime from the messages so I have the username and the time of the latest message on top and the messages in the bubble. I have try adding extra divs but still no luck.

Comment: acutely you write an if and i changed second part of if and else after { True ? 'do something : "do something else' } and i change something else partition